# Como imprimir o nome do usuário após logar no site, só que em outras páginas

Tags: php

então, eu quero fazer o seguinte, quero que quando um usuário no meu site acessar sua conta, o nome dele aparaça em um determinado local do site, isso eu sei fazer, pego a sessão dele e imprimo, tipo isso: $_Session['name'];. Só que quero fazer o mesmo em outras parte do meu site, como posso fazer?

Comment: Tentou usar `session_start()` nas páginas que queres que esses dados estejam disponíveis?  Essa função irá disponibilizar na global `$_SESSION` os dados da sessão do domínio na página atual.

Comment: SIm, mas eu faço isso e deu, só que quero que o nome dele apareça em uma outra página, ex: quando o user entra ele vai pra uma página especifica pra ele, quero que quando ele volte pra página inicial do site aparecer o nome dele, entendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, 
Você só precisa iniciar a seção na pagina e dar o comando de impressão no local desejado como no exemplo:

```
 <?php

if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
  session_start();
}//inicia a seção

$_SESSION['name'] = $nome_do_usuario;

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <body>
    <div> <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?> </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Dessa forma você conseguirá acessar qualquer valor salvo na sua $_SESSION !

Comment: Então amigo, tentei isso e não vai pow, tipo, acho que vc entendeu errado, olha só, Quando o usuário ele loga na conta dele ele é redirecionado para uma página chamada Minhaconta e nessa página pega a sessão dele e aparecer o nome dele de boa na página, só que quando eu volto pra página inicial, não consigo apresentar o nome dele, e coloquei esse código da erro de index por causa do name.

Comment: Você está salvando o nome dele na $_SESSION? Por caso esteja você poderá acessar em qualquer outra página.

Comment: SIm, já consegui o que eu queria kkk ;)